# send json to php (jquery)

Tags: php, jquery, json

I am trying to pass a Json obtained by a `json.stringify` process of an html table to a php file to insert it into a database.
First,wanted to check is the code below is ok : i get the right output of the json when doing an alert of 'myjson':

```
var myjson=  JSON.stringify(mydata);
alert(myjson);

[{},{"product[]":"john","qty[]":"288","price[]":"199","total[]":"57312"},{"product[]":"sylvia","qty[]":"12","price[]":"13","total[]":"156"},{"product[]":"juan","qty[]":"11","price[]":"9","total[]":"99"},{"total_amount":"57567.00"}]
```

then i have this ajax to send it to php (test.php):

```
$.ajax({
url: "test.php",
type: "POST",
data: myjson,
dataType: "JSON",
success: function (data) {
    alert(data);

}
```

});

And my php file to check if the output is fine:

```
$obj = json_decode($_POST["mydata"]);

echo $obj->var;
```

but i do not get anything in my alert once the php is supposedly processed?

what is wrong?

Comment: Why should `mydata` mean anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you will need to post the data with a name, more specifically with the name "mydata".

Currently the PHP looking for a post called mydata ($_POST["mydata"]) which is not available and throws the following Notice  `Undefined index: mydata`

To do that, you can change the data you're sending from:

```
data: myjson
```

to

```
data: {"mydata": myjson}
```

Second, the data sent to the back-end is an array of objects

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [product[]] => john
            [qty[]] => 288
            [price[]] => 199
            [total[]] => 57312
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [product[]] => sylvia
            [qty[]] => 12
            [price[]] => 13
            [total[]] => 156
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [product[]] => juan
            [qty[]] => 11
            [price[]] => 9
            [total[]] => 99
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [total_amount] => 57567.00
        )

)
```

You will need to access them by index or iterate through the array.

Access them by index: `$obj[0]->var` or `$obj[1]->var`

Last but not least, the properties contain square brackets `{"product[]":"john","qty[]":"288","price[]":"199","total[]":"57312"}` which is not recommended but will still work. Accessing the properties should be done like: `$obj[1]->{'property[]'}`

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function  sendAjax(){
        var mydata = [{},    {"product[]":"john","qty[]":"288","price[]":"199","total[]":"57312"},    {"product[]":"sylvia","qty[]":"12","price[]":"13","total[]":"156"},{"product[]":"juan","qty[]":"11","price[]":"9","total[]":"99"},{"total_amount":"57567.00"}]
        var myjson =  JSON.stringify(mydata);

        $.ajax({
            url: "test.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {"mydata": myjson},
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    $obj = json_decode($_POST["mydata"]);
    echo $obj[1]->{'product[]'};
?>
```

**Update:**

The AJAX is expecting a JSON response, otherwise it will fail. In the Back-End you will need to change the response to JSON.

```
<?php
    $obj = json_decode($_POST["mydata"]);
    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    echo json_encode($obj[1]->{'product[]'});
?>
```